# Designer Workflow: Triggering on Delete?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, updatelistitems, delete

So I have created a custom task list which has 4 sub lists that are identical. When the business area is selected in one of the choice columns on the list this will then copy the item to the relevant sub list (original essentially being the master list of all tasks).

I have created a workflow to keep everything synchronized (Any changes made in the master or sub will be reflected in both lists)

Now the only problem is if an item is deleted in either the master or the sub list this will not be reflected in the other. Is there a workflow I could use to check if the item has been deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Trigerring a workflow on item deletion is not available.
Please use item deleted event reciever to handle the scenario